# I am not getting any return response data in SSE [Server Sent Event] EventSource onMessage object from Flask backend?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, server-sent-events

onMessage object is not receiving any data from backend. Why it is happening. Here is my code using flask in backend.

flask.py

```
@app.route("/ride-list/",methods=["POST","GET"])
@cross_origin(origin='localhost',headers=['Content- Type','Authorization'])
def ride_list():
    conn=sqlite3.connect('shyori.db')
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    result=cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ride;")
    result=list(result)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    resp=jsonify(ride=result)
    resp.content_type="text/event-stream"
    return resp
```

demo.js

```
<script>
    var source=new EventSource("http://127.0.0.1:5000/ride-list/");
    console.log(source.onMessage);
    source.onMessage=function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried attaching error event to EventSource instance? Should m be lowercase at onmessage?

Comment: i tried both m and M. Yes i attached error event. I got this is in console.log()

Event {isTrusted: true, type: "error", target: EventSource, currentTarget: EventSource, eventPhase: 2…}

Comment: Is server side response properly formatted and escaped? Is response JSON?

Comment: Yes response is in JSON.  It got nothing.

Comment: Response should be string ending with \n or \n\n

Comment: I am not getting any error. If that I got error. But I didnt get any error. It got nothing. I tried with w3schools demo php code also. But same result.

Comment: See https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/#toc-introduction

Comment: I tried this tutorial :(

Answer (score 4):

You should use **data:** msg like this,

before your msg put **data:**...

Event Stream Format

Sending an event stream from the source is a matter of constructing a plaintext response, served with a text/event-stream Content-Type, that follows the SSE format. In its basic form, the response should contain a "data:" line, followed by your message, followed by two "\n" characters to end the stream:

```
data: My message\n\n
```

Comment: I had no idea `\n\n` was required. Thank you.